# CSS Grid Layout adapting size

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a school project, which is a board game, i have to place multiple players on one filed of the board, i want to make that with grid layout, but i cant figure out the right placement.

I want to make it that if there is only one div inside the container it takes up the whole space.
If there is two div's inside the container it takes up half the space with the two items beside each other.
If there is three-four div's inside its in two row's each row with two div's beside each other.

My current code is :

```css
#board td{
    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

#board td .playersDiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;

}

#board td .playersDiv div{
    background-image: url('red.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="board">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="playersDiv">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would using flex be an option?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: you said *if there is only one div inside the container it takes up the whole space. If there is two div's inside the container it takes up half the space*. Is the container you're talking about `. playersDiv`? in your code sample there 3 divs, does it means you can have more than 2? Is there a maximum?

Comment: The container is ".playersDiv". The maximum divs inside is 4. The minimum divs inside is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

- Your code already works for 2, 3 and 4 `DIV`s inside `playersDiv`.
- When there is only 1 `DIV` it needs to span over the 2 columns. This can be  achieved using `:only-child` selector and `grid-column` property.

```css
#board td {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#board td .playersDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

#board td .playersDiv div {
  /* I've change these lines so we can see the DIVs in the snippet */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#board td .playersDiv div:only-child {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<table id="board">
  <tr>
    <!-- 1 div -->
    <td>
      <div class="playersDiv">
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <!-- 2 div -->
    <td>
      <div class="playersDiv">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <!-- 3 div -->
    <td>
      <div class="playersDiv">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <!-- 4 div -->
    <td>
      <div class="playersDiv">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, it almost works correctly, but in the first scenario it should take up the whole space.[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDNcQ.png)

Comment: I figured it out from your answer, I added one more line there: `grid-row: span 2;`. And now it works. Thank you.